# Kafka Streams: Delay processing after rebalancing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

[image]

I have Kafka Streams Application that reads from a topic with 50 partitions. The application aggregates data for a specific key and writes it into a state store. Therefore it is important, that the same key is always written to the same partition. This works well. When the traffic is high, I create n new instances of my app. Then, of course, rebalancing happens and the consumer-to-partition assignment changes. The problem is, that the rebalancing is happening multiple times within seconds, each time when a new consumer is added to the consumer group.

```
{"timestamp":"2023-03-24T08:30:25.779Z","message":"Application state changed from RUNNING to REBALANCING"}
{"timestamp":"2023-03-24T08:30:37.438Z","message":"Application state changed from REBALANCING to RUNNING"}
{"timestamp":"2023-03-24T08:30:37.471Z","message":"Application state changed from RUNNING to REBALANCING"}
{"timestamp":"2023-03-24T08:30:37.598Z","message":"Application state changed from REBALANCING to RUNNING"}
{"timestamp":"2023-03-24T08:30:40.897Z","message":"Application state changed from RUNNING to REBALANCING"}
{"timestamp":"2023-03-24T08:30:41.073Z","message":"Application state changed from REBALANCING to RUNNING"}
{"timestamp":"2023-03-24T08:30:41.270Z","message":"Application state changed from RUNNING to REBALANCING"}
{"timestamp":"2023-03-24T08:30:41.333Z","message":"Application state changed from REBALANCING to RUNNING"}
```

Problem: After the first rebalancing, the consumer starts to consume and aggregate messages from the new partition. A short time after that it is again rebalanced and the consumer is allocated to another partition. Then the aggregation for a specific key is "lost" and the new consumer (and state store) allocated to this partition starts from beginning.

Question: Is it possible to tell kafka "delay processing of new messages after rebalancing for n seconds, to make sure that the whole rebalancing process in finished"?

Answer (score 1):

The only configuration that comes close to what you're looking for is the
[group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms), but this configuration only takes effect for a ***new*** group, not an existing one where more members have been added.

But you need to remember that Kafka Streams uses a changelog to back state stores.  This means that when a task gets assigned to a new host, that host will restore the state store to the last record in the changelog, so it's not starting over from scratch but from the latest record in the changelog.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I cannot make use of the state store logging functionality because I disabled it to speed up startup time of the app as I have a lot of data.